# In memory caching for large data sets at the ASP .net server

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, iis-7

I am working on a 3-tier project management application (IIS server + Application server + DB server). We have a large JSON data (~1 MB) that we need to cache in memory so that we can minimize the db calls to fetch that. There may be ~10-50 users simultaneously logged in and the total cache size may vary between 10-50 MB.

I can not use a caching server as it will add dependency on another server and we will need to check whether its up or not so avoid any problem downstream. 
Its not a "highly scalable" application so i want to use something easy to implement and that can be performant for above parameters.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are caching 1mb per user ? Are you unable to cache the data at the client end ?

Comment: 10-50Mb is "large amount of data"? You can probably host such site on your phone without much trouble... If 10Mb is amount of memory you are so worried about ASP.Net (or .Net in general) is probably not a acceptable at all... Have you actually measured cache usage (i.e. default ASP.Net cache have plenty of counters to watch) to confirm that 10-50Mb will cause problems for your application?

Comment: 1-10 mb per user. Its basically a temporary data on which user is working. I am in fact going to try browser cache (ext JS store).

Answer (score 0):

there is several solution  you can use NOSQL like memcache or redis or etc you also can  use .net memory cache : "System.Runtime.Caching" : ObjectCache or if your using MSSQL 2012 you could use MSSQL memory table